Change font of TextField without affecting context menu
Setting a custom font style on a TextField in JavaFX will also affect its default context menu, I noticed. What can I do to change the font of the user input, but keep the menu items in the context menu as they would show up normally?
.custom-text-field {
  -fx-alignment: center;
  -fx-font-size: 2.5em;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-font-family: monospaced;
}

I'm searching for a solution in CSS style, I do not want to alter the font in Java code.
The documentation of the TextField component has been of little use.
Neither has checking the default CSS style in caspian.css helped me much, unfortunately.

The reason this happens is that the context menu is a (direct) descendant of its control (see the documentation for ContextMenu), and the default value for a font is inherit, so by default the context menu will inherit the font from the control to which it is attached.
One way is to specifically reset the style for the context menu:
.custom-text-field {
  -fx-alignment: center;
  -fx-font-size: 2.5em;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-font-family: monospaced;
}
.custom-text-field > .context-menu * {
    -fx-font: null;
}

If you want to "globally" enforce the rule "don't inherit context menu's fonts from their control", the following more general CSS rule will do this:
.context-menu {
    -fx-font: null;
}

(This removes the inherit value for the context menu's font.)

That would work, thank you! But we need to override/restore the style of the context menu explicitly, there is no CSS selector that's more specific to change the font of the input field only (not bothering about resetting the context menu's font)?

@user1438038 I don't believe there is (though I may be wrong), because the default value for font properties is to inherit them from the parent. Consequently changing the font for the text field will change it for any descendants.

@user1438038 Also note, in case this fits your needs marginally better, you can be a bit less specific with the context menu selector: .context-menu { -fx-font:null;} will force all context menus to use the platform-default font instead of assuming inherit; i.e. it will prevent the font in any control overriding the font in its context menu

I'd rather not enforce that rule globally, but good to know. I'll stick with resetting the context menu only for this specific input field. Thanks again!
